# SQL Condition where in terms of Variable

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I wanted some help in making condition where clause. What I am trying to do is if one of the variables I am using is empty then use a specific where clause else use that variable

So for example, I have Customer Table, Having Customer, and other Customer Details. In addition to that, I also have InsertDate and UpdateDate.

```
Declare @CustomerID Nvarchar(20) = '';
Declare @StartDate Date = '2019-05-05'
Declare @EndDate Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1);
```

Here I have kept @CustomerID as Empty. So if that is empty then find data using InsertDate between @StartDate and @EndDate else find data via CustomerID.

But when I am trying to do that I am having an issue with that.

```
Select
   * 
From
   CustomerDetals 
where
   (
      Case
         When
            ISNULL(@CustomerID, '') = '' 
         Then
            Convert(Date, InsertDate) >= @StartDate 
            and Convert(Date, InsertDate) <= @EndDate 
         Else
            CustomerID = @CustomerID 
      End
   )
```

Error I am getting is

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

How can I solve this?

If you are unclear or not sure about this post we can discuss in the comment instead of directly downgrading the post.

Comment: The biggest issue here is that you seem to think that an empty string is a valid integer. There will be an implicit conversion to int which will return 0.

Comment: @SeanLange I have modified the query with the specific error I am getting

Comment: Oh dear I didn't even notice this earlier. You can't use a case expression to control logical processing. It is used to return a scalar value. You can't have a boolean check in the output of your case. That is not at all how this works.

Comment: @SeanLange Then what is your solution in this case? If you wanted to have a dynamic where clause where one is empty use another condition...

Answer (score 0):

> 1.You can use this statement

```
    Select * CustomerDetals 
    where (  ISNULL(@CustomerID, '')= 0 and Convert(Date, InsertDate) >= 
    @StartDate and Convert(Date, InsertDate)<=@EndDate ) 
    or (CustomerID = @CustomerID )
```

> 2.You can write dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000) 
Declare @CustomerID Nvarchar(20) = '' 
Declare @StartDate Date = '2019-05-05'
Declare @EndDate Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1);
SET @sqlCommand = 'Select * from CustomerDetals where 1=1 '

IF ISNULL(@CustomerID, '')= ''
BEGIN
     SET @sqlCommand +=' and Convert(Date, InsertDate) >='''+ @StartDate + ''' and 
     Convert(Date, InsertDate)<= ''' + @EndDate + ''''
END

ELSE     
BEGIN
     SET @sqlCommand +=' and CustomerID = ''' + @CustomerID + ''''
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Comment: Second seems to be fine to me but when you have really long query then executing via this `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand` is not feasible. And first one my requirement - If @CustomerID as Empty then have where clause as InsertDate between @StartDate and @EndDate. If CustomerID is not empty then find data based on CustomerID

Answer (score 0):

Where do I begin.  First of all, format your code properly so it's easier to read.

```
Select * CustomerDetals 
where (
    Case 
        When ISNULL(@CustomerID, '')= '' Then Convert(Date, InsertDate) >= @StartDate and Convert(Date, InsertDate)<=@EndDate 
        Else CustomerID = @CustomerID 
    End
)
```

First error, there is no `FROM` keyword.
Second error, what are you trying to do in the `CASE` statement?  It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: For your first question - that was a typo error while typing for this post. For your second question - If variable CustomerID as Empty then have where clause as InsertDate between variable StartDate and variable EndDate. If CustomerID is not empty then find data based on CustomerID. Hope this explaination is understandable

Comment: This will never work as coded here. Look at the case expression. That is not how they work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this like this query.

```
Select * 
From CustomerDetals 
WHERE
(
    Convert(Date, InsertDate) >= @StartDate 
    and 
    Convert(Date, InsertDate) <= @EndDate 
    AND
    @CustomerID IS NULL
)
OR 
(
    CustomerID = @CustomerID
)
```

Comment: Based on first where condition, this will always return 0 data. So I am doing it in another way if variable -  @CustomerID is null then execute query with StartDate and EndDate. Else execute another query with only CustomerID